# How to calculate the instant rate of a gauge metric?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, monitoring, prometheus, grafana, metrics

How can I calculate the per-second instant rate of increase of the time series in Prometheus or Grafana without using rate() or irate()?

This drive function is not helping to achieve the same result as irate

```
irate(node_cpu_seconds_total[5m]) 

deriv(node_cpu_seconds_total_gauge[5m])
```

Actually I need to calculate the per-second instant rate of increase of the time series of Gauge metric data which is a modified counter metric type data.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`deriv()`](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#deriv) for that. Here is an example:

```
deriv(process_virtual_memory_bytes{job="$job", instance="$instance"}[$__interval])
```

[image]

Comment: This function is not helping to  achieve same result as  irate(node_cpu_seconds_total[5m]) for deriv(node_cpu_seconds_total_gauge[5m])

Comment: Ah so you want the irate equivalent. I'm pretty sure there is none and probably for a good reason. I guess you could try to "fake" it by using `deriv` with a range that is just big enough for two data points to fit in and a min step in Grafana that is greater than the range you are using for `deriv`.

Answer (score 1):

Prometheus doesn't provide `irate()` equivalent for [gauge](https://prometheus.io/docs/concepts/metric_types/#gauge) time series :(

If you still need it, then try [ideriv](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#ideriv) function from VictoriaMetrics. It returns the derivative based on two last samples for the time series:

```
ideriv(metric_name[5m])
```

Note that both `irate()` and `ideriv()` functions don't capture spikes, since they perform calculations based on a subset of raw samples, while ignoring the rest of samples. See [this article](https://valyala.medium.com/why-irate-from-prometheus-doesnt-capture-spikes-45f9896d7832) for details. If you need capturing spikes, then take a look at [rollup_deriv](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#rollup_deriv) function. It reliably captures `min`, `max` and `avg` derivative based on all the raw samples, which hit the given lookbehind window in square brackets.